# Quelle est la différence entre objet et objectif ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Dans le contexte de la finalité, notre livre de français propose comme synonymes pour *but* les mots *objectif* (que je connais), mais également *objet*.

Exemple:

> Ce regime a pour but de…

Est-ce que *Ce régime a pour objet de…* se dit vraiment ou n'y a-t-il pas un léger changement de sens?

Answer (score 3):

*Objet* est plutôt un synonyme de *sujet*, mais peut être utilisé au figuré dans le sens de *but* (cf http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/objet sens 8 et http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/objet sens 9).

De mon point de vue de francophone maternel, l'utilisation de *objet* dans le sens de *but* me paraît moins fréquente, et l'expression *avoir pour objet de* ne m'est pas familière, contrairement à *avoir pour objectif/but de*.

Comment: Merci, c'est bien ce que j'avais ressenti!

Answer (score 3):

Bien qu'ils soient tout à fait interchangeables dans la majorité des cas, on peut nuancer en s'appuyant sur les définitions du petit Robert :

> ... a pour *but* : a pour *cible* (à atteindre), a pour *terme* (sera alors achevé)
>  ... a pour *objet* : veut réaliser,
>   matérialiser
>  ... à pour *objectif* : concerne une réalisation conceptuelle

*Objet* s'emploie plus difficilement dans l'expression '*a pour objet*' que dans les exemples cités par Frederic

Comment: Remarque très utile, merci!

Answer (score 2):

L'objet désigne la matière **à** laquelle il chaut, par comparaison avec le sujet qui est la matière **de** laquelle il est question.
Dans leurs utilisations, la différence entre *but* et *objet* est plutôt subtile, j'essaye ici d'illustrer ça avec un ou deux exemples bien choisis.

Une personne peut avoir un but : ce qu'elle espère faire, réaliser, qui est la raison de ses actes.
Elle n'a généralement pas d’objet. Sauf si elle a été créée (c'est à dire, placée dans une situation) dans un *but* particulier, par d'autres. Dans ce cas, l'*objet* de cette personne (en tant que moyen) est le *but* ou la *raison* de ceux qui l'ont créée ou placée là. De façon plus absolue, lorsqu'elle se trouve seule dans une situation, on peut parler de l'objet de sa présence ou de l'objet de son existence.

De la même façon, l'objet¹ d'une lettre c'est le but (indirectement exprimé) que la personne recherche en l'écrivant — la chose qui lui importe. Mais il est commun d’attribuer *transitivement*² un but, voire peut-être poétiquement une volonté, à la lettre elle-même, ou à d'autres inanimés…

*But* et *objectif* sont eux plutôt similaires, le premier contient une notion de finalité alors que le deuxième indique plus une direction ou un point d'arrivée.

—
<sup>1. Oui en français les lettres sont généralement intitulées par un objet plutôt que par un sujet. On ne discute pas de quelque chose, on pointe vers de la matière, souvent on demande à ce que quelque chose soit fait…</sup>
<sup>2. [Sens 2](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/transitif) du Wiktionaire.</sup>

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour la réponse!

Comment: 1. Pourriez-vous expliciter le Sens 2 du Wikitionnaire, à savoir : *Se dit d’une cause dont l’action s’exerce sur un objet étranger au sujet agissant* ? J'imaginerais que ça signifie : La cause mène une action qui s'exerce sur un objet/objectif envers un sujet active ?

Comment: 2. D'ailleurs, pourriez-vous détailler : *L'objet désigne la matière à laquelle **il** chaut* ? Quel est l'antécédent de **il** ?

Comment: @LePressentiment: Pour le 1. Cette définition n'est pas facile à déchiffrer, mais l'exemple de la lettre est plutôt pas mal. La lettre n'a pas vraiment de “cause”, seul celui qui l'écrit (le sujet actif) en a une. Pourtant on lui en attribue une tout de même.

Comment: Pour le 2. J'ai utilisé *chaloir* assez artificiellement pour faire apparaître la préposition “*à*” qui décrit bien l'idée derrière ce sens du mot *objet*, mais ce verbe est presque complètement tombé en désuétude. C'est un verbe impersonnel, le *il* n'a pas d’antécédent. J'aurais aussi pu écrire “à laquelle on s’intéresse”, même si l'intuition n'est pas aussi bonne pour la suite.

Answer (score -1):

Pour moi, le *but* est la finalité.

L'*objectif* est tout ce qu'il faut d'abord exécuter pour atteindre le but .